# jquery .html().show() displays blank page in IE 7-9

Tags: jquery

I have the code below which takes input from hidden inputs, checkboxes and textboxes, converts them into arrays and then posts them to addEntries.php, which should replace the current page.

I opted to use the method below as I couldn't get a basic form to submit the arrays properly. Also, I opted to use arrays as each time the form is generated, it will have a different number of options, depending on the athlete's age, which level they compete at etc.

It all works fine, the entries are added to the table.

The only issue is that when testing in IE 7-9, it returns a blank page, although when I view the source of the page, I see the original page source, not the source generated by the $.post function.

It works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE 10.

I suspect my trouble is the $('html').html(result).show(); line being incompatible with IE 7-9 and am hoping someone might have an alternative for me.

TIA!

Grant

```
function submitEntries() {

$(function(){
  var athID = $("input[name='athID\\[\\]']")
  .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

  var MeetID = $("input[name='MeetID\\[\\]']")
  .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

  var EventID = $("input[name='EventID\\[\\]']")
  .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

  var athEnter = [];
  $("input[name='athEnter\\[\\]']:checkbox").map(function()
    { 
        this.checked ? athEnter.push('1') : athEnter.push('0'); 
    });

  var athSeed = $("input[name='athSeed\\[\\]']")
  .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

  var session_email = $("input[name='session_email']")
  .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

$.post('addEntries.php',
{ 'athID[]':      athID,
  'MeetID[]':     MeetID,
  'EventID[]':    EventID,
  'athEnter[]':   athEnter,
  'athSeed[]':    athSeed,
  'session_email': session_email },
  function(result) {
    $('html').empty();
$('html').html(result).show();
  });
 });
};
```

Comment: I had an issue like that recently. The problem was the IE browser was in the wrong document mode, I don't know if that's your problem, but may be worth checking.